# Copy data from one workbook to other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you for your help!
How to change this code to copy data to existing workbooks (the only difference they are in .xlsm format, the names of files are 1.xlsm,...,50.xlsm) not to create new ones (all files are in the same folder)? And how to specify range `lm = Range("B2,G2,L2")` if there are more cells (every 5-th cell, starting from B2)?

I've tried to copy data to existing workbooks using `Workbooks.Open ("1.xlsm")` 
`Workbooks.Open ("2.xlsm")` etc. and when it must be saved adding `& ".xlsm"` to the name (as `SaveAs`).

```
Sub CopyM()
  Dim lm As Range, r As Long, c As Long
  Set lm = Range("B2,G2,L2"):  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For r = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Workbooks.Add
    For c = 0 To 4
      lm.Offset(r - 2, c).Copy Cells(r + c, 2)
    Next
    With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
      .SaveAs lm.Offset(r - 2, -1).Value: .Close
    End With
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  You'll probably get better responses if you say what you've already tried that didn't work, and where you've already looked for information.  You might try looking up `Workbooks` and `Range` in the Excel VBA help.

Comment: Thank you aucuparia, I have problems with using workbooks.open (adding data to existing workbooks), I'm learning VBA right now and it's a little bit difficult for me.

Comment: ok, great - can I suggest editing the question to say "I've tried using `workbooks.open` like this <add some code> but it didn't work because xyz happened"?

Comment: Ok thank you aucuparia, I will follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that you need a way to refer to the correct workbook once you've opened it.  The way to do this is by assigning the `workbook` to an object variable, then use that variable every time you need to refer to the workbook:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("yourfilename.xlsx")
'...
  lm.Offset(r - 2, c).Copy wb.Cells(r + c, 2)
'...
With wb
  .SaveAs lm.Offset(r - 2, -1).Value: .Close
End With
```

For adding extra cells to the `range`, you could just type additional cell references separated by commas (e.g. `Range("B2,G2,L2,Q2,V2")`).  This is ok if those cells don't ever change.  Alternatively for more flexibility you can add additional cells to `lm` in a loop using the `Union()` function, e.g.:

```
Dim col As Long
Dim lm As Range
Set lm = Range("B2")
For col = 7 To 256 Step 5
  Set lm = Union(lm, Cells(2, col))
Next col
```

Comment: Thank you very much aucuparia for your help!